# json getting the right data on php

Tags: php, arrays, json

How do I get the output of Apple to be fruit and Beef to be meat with this kind of JSON? Is it even possible to get that data?

P.S. each array's first index will always be 1.

Example of desired output:

1. Apple -> fruit
2. Beef -> meat
3. Celery -> vegetable

```js
{
    "Apple": {
        "fruit": "1"
    },
    "Beef": {
        "meat" : "1"
    },
    "Celery": {
        "vegetable" : "1"
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show us how you are generating the JSON?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `json_decode`:

```
$obj = json_decode( $jsonString );
echo $obj->Apple->fruit;
```

*et voila!*

**PS:** Your above JSON is unvalid (maybe a typo): please add a `:` after `"Celery"`

**PS2:** each array's first index is not `1`, index(es) are 'Apple', 'Beef' and 'Celery'.

Comment: Hi fusion3k, thanks for answering my question. However, what if there's a lot more arrays and they only have 1 index of a value 1 and I need to return those indexes name. Is it possible?

Comment: Please edit your own question adding **concrete** example: “arrays and they only have 1 index of a value 1” sounds like not valid.